# How to map domain to web application deployed on Tomcat 7 in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

I have a Java based web application which is deployed on Ubuntu machine. I can access the web application at localhost:8080 and it is working as expected.

Now I have domain name for the web application and I want to access web application through the browser using the domain name(http://www.xyz.com).

I want to know the steps which are required to achieve it. Before posting this question, I search over the google.

I have already added the host details in the conf/server.xml.

```
   <Host name="xyz.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Alias>www.xyz.com</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="" debug="0" privileged="true" />
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"    
              directory="logs"   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" 
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
   </Host>
```

Also, I made changes in the /etc/hostname and added following

```
      <IP Address>   www.xyz.com    xyz
```

What else do I  need to do?

Comment: you should add DNS record in your domain settings maping your domain to your server's ip address then you can access it domain:8080.